# How to define a range in SAS graph

Tags: graph, sas

I have a question in SAS. I am trying to get a scatter plot of zip codes vs average income data. I run the code below and obtain a graph but the Y range for zip code goes from 0 - 6xxxx. I need to the Y range to be from 50000 - 6xxxx. How could I achieve that?

```
proc sgplot;
scatter y=zipcode x=Avg_income;
title ’Zip code vs average income ’;
run;;
```

Comment: Do you mean the axis should go from 5-6000? Or do you also need to restrict your data?

Comment: what is the differernce between the two? I mean right now the all my scatter points are in the 60000-69000 range and below that its all empty as the Y axis starts from 0. I want the Y axis to start from 60000. ( I am just focusing on Chicago zip codes )

Comment: my zip codes are only in the 60000-69000 range

Comment: Check your data, SAS usually limits the range to your data.

Comment: I see what you are saying - let me check....